# create a trigger before insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I want to create a trigger before insert and check inside the trigger function the summary_id values of the new row to be inserted, to see if the summary_id already exists in the table. if it exists then the trigger should return null as I don't want to insert duplicate values. I have written this function, but, when I tried to add a new duplicate row, it was inserted successfully!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_ack_bi()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
--DECLARE
--    max_points INTEGER;
BEGIN

   IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        IF NEW.ack_summary_id = (SELECT ack_summary_id FROM scm_main.tbl_ack WHERE scm_main.tbl_ack.ack_summary_id = NEW.ack_summary_id LIMIT 1) THEN
               RETURN NULL;
        ELSE
               RETURN NEW;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_ack_bi BEFORE INSERT ON
scm_main.tbl_ack
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_ack_bi()


ALTER FUNCTION trigger_ack_bi() OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Why not just create a unique index and handle any errors coming from that? Much more reliable and faster than a trigger

Comment: could you expand your comment to be more understandable please

Comment: Make the column `NOT NULL` and create a unique index: `create unique index on tbl_ack(ack_summary_id)`. That's all you need, no trigger required

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting column to be NOT NULL and creating a PK on it...

```
alter table scm_main.tbl_ack alter column ack_summary_id set NOT NULL;
alter table scm_main.tbl_ack add primary key (ack_summary_id);
```

Comment: it's complicated, I have already done those. I just need the trigger function to work.

Comment: @user3313098: what's "complicated" about a PK or unique constraint?

Comment: ack_id is already a primary key in the table. and the table has already been created. my question is that wouldn't adding one more primary key complicate or modify the table relation according to its relation to the other tables and foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

it seems the trigger function is correct. But, it is running in silent mode. raising an exception was what I needed to make sure that duplication had been prevented. Thank you for your other solutions.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_ack_bi()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
--DECLARE
--    max_points INTEGER;
BEGIN

   IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        IF NEW.ack_summary_id IS NULL THEN
             RAISE EXCEPTION 'summaryID cannot be null';
        END IF;

        IF NEW.ack_summary_id = (SELECT ack_summary_id FROM scm_main.tbl_ack WHERE scm_main.tbl_ack.ack_summary_id = NEW.ack_summary_id LIMIT 1) THEN
             RAISE EXCEPTION 'duplication prevented..';
               RETURN NULL;
        ELSE
               RETURN NEW;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_ack_bi BEFORE INSERT ON
scm_main.tbl_ack
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_ack_bi()
```